# App crash with proguard on Xiaomi Device, logcat empty

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I have a strange trouble with my app when I use it on Xiaomi.

My app is already created is ready to be used. When I use it from android studio without proguard, or when the apk is released without proguard, it works on all the device.

If I use proguard, for some reasons, it stop working for the Xiaomi devices ( I tried with several Xiaomi Mi-4c, the behavior is the same anytime, it crashes while it's working without proguard ).

The thing is the logcat remains empty when I try to debug my app with proguard on those Xiaomi device, and therefore I have no way to know why it is crashing.

Here is my current proguard config:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn net.sqlcipher.**
-dontwarn com.uservoice.uservoicesdk.**
-dontwarn oauth.signpost.commonshttp.**

-verbose

-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.** { public *; }

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** {
    *;
}
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

-keep class com.uservoice.uservoicesdk.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
```

Also on my `build.gradle` file, I set `debuggable true`

How can I know the reason of the crash? I tried to kill/start adb, I activated the USB debug mode, but the logcat remains empty.

Thanks in advance

Comment: proguard will work with release build only. So , you will not get any logcat outputs

Comment: The result is the same in debug or release; however you are suppose to be able to get the crash log if you set the release build as debuggable